# What does the Astral Sea look like?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, astral

I am making a campaign where a tarrasque is on a rampage, and the players have to ask a deity to help them defeat it. I was thinking of making them go to the different planes where they could find a deity, like the Astral Sea, but I have no idea how it looks.

Does it look like a big ocean where you can find some islands with gods, or is the *sea* term just to represent an imagery like the Milky Way looks like milk?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### If the astral plane is a "sea," you are a fish

There is a description of the astral plane in the Dungeon Masters Guide (p. 46-47, bold added). There, it states:

> The Astral Plane is the realm of thought and dream, where visitors travel as disembodied souls to reach the Outer Planes. **It is a great silvery sea, the same above and below, with swirling wisps of white and gray streaking among motes of light like distant stars.**
>
> Most of the Astral Sea is a vast, empty expanse. Visitors  occasionally stumble upon the petrified corpse of a dead god or other chunks of rock drifting forever in the silvery void. Much more commonplace are color pools- magical pools of colored light that flicker like radiant, spinning coins.

When you hear that the astral plane is like a "sea," it's natural to picture it from the surface of the water, because that's the main way that humans interact with the sea. But **the astral plane is more like a sea with no surface or floor**.  Although you might find solid material there, the concept of an "island" is somewhat misleading. Also, note one other important detail (DMG, p. 47):

> Creatures on the Astral Plane don't age or suffer from hunger or thirst.

So you could find any number of living things in the astral plane without finding any "land" for them to live on. Unlike the material plane, traditional life isn't necessarily tied to any particular ecosystem. In other words, the plane could essentially contain anything or nothing. The only limits are what you can think of: because thoughts are precisely the source and nature of the astral plane.

Comment: <comments removed> @Fanlyoko If you have a new question about the planes, please post a new question with the [Ask Question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I think really leaning into the 'sea' metaphor would be pretty cool. The idea of the party just kinda flying through space like Superman always seemed a little silly to me, but I love the idea of riding a strange silvery ship across an infinite mercury sea.